# How to omit heading in df -k command of LinuxIA64 using regex

Tags: regex

I have the below output

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3             60300484  18883824  38304156  34% /
/dev/sda1              1046516      8604   1037912   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                  4120800         0   4120800   0% /dev/shm
psnfs1:/SDepot     629145600 400663744 228481856  64% /depot
psnfs1:/vol/ghome/ghome/support/kumar
                     1287651328 1065510400 222140928  83% /home/kumar
psnfs2:/vol/us_nhome2/us_nishome2/shaw
                     1073741888 799816192 273925696  75% /home/shaw
psnfs2:/vol/us_nhome2/us_nishome2/asimon
                     1073741888 799816192 273925696  75% /home/asimon
```

Where I am using `(?xms)(^[/\w:]+.*?)(?=^[/\w:]+|\Z)` to get each row, later i use `\s` to extract each column values from the prev regex output, but the problem is I also get the headings `(Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on)`. How can i omit them? Also explain the regex please :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're building this into a shell pipeline, it'd probably be easier to use `tail(1)` than building an even more complicated regex:

```
$ df -k
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3             11811504   7979960   3231544  72% /
none                   3054508       300   3054208   1% /dev
...
```

vs

```
$ df -k | tail -n+2
/dev/sda3             11811504   7979960   3231544  72% /
none                   3054508       300   3054208   1% /dev
none                   3061428       596   3060832   1% /dev/shm
...
```

From the `tail(1)` manpage:

```
   -n, --lines=K
          output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; or
          use -n +K to output lines starting with the Kth
```

And if it were me, I'd probably use `awk(1)` to get to specific columns:

```
$ df -k |tail -n+2 | awk '{print $5, $6;}'
72% /
1% /dev
1% /dev/shm
1% /var/run
0% /var/lock
72% /var/lib/ureadahead/debugfs
59% /boot
34% /home
```

Comment: I have no idea how this awk works, but `tail` is pretty good, for future references can you explain me a little about `awk`? Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @Abhishek, `awk` is a standard language that makes some common text-oriented jobs easier. It takes a matching specification and a code block and executes the code block on input _records_ that match the regex. My last example could also be written `df -k | awk '/\// {print $5, $6;}'` -- the regex `/\//` matches a single `/` anywhere in the record (by default lines) and then prints the fifth and sixth fields. While `awk` can be used to write very complicated programs, I like it best for short one-liners -- much longer than that and it can become difficult to read compared to Perl, Ruby, Python.

Comment: Thanks look into some tuts also :)